# How can I send a file to mail in html form using http request in nodejs server code?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, email

What I am doing is when node server runs a user can type 1 or 2 or any other number.If user types 1 then I will print a message in response.When user types 2 then I will display a choose file button so that user can send an email with a file.When user enters other than these two numbers I will display a response message.Actually I am able to send a mail when user enters 2.Now I want to send a file when user enters 2.Attaching file manually like reading file from system this I already done.But I want to send with http request.I was struct at this point.So how can I solve this issue.Any help will be appreciated.

And here is my HTML code i.e, samplereal.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").hide();
    $("#sub").click(function(){
    if($("#myinp").val() == 1 ) {
        $("#myForm").hide();
        $("#new").text("Email sent without attachment");
        } 
        else if ($("#myinp").val() == 2) {
        $("#myForm").show();
        $("#new").text("");
        }
        else {
        $("#myForm").hide();
        $("#new").text("Email Cannot be send");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="number" id="myinp" placeholder="enter 1 or 2"/>
<button id="sub">Send Mail</button>
<form id="myForm" action="/sendForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="order" value="2" > 
<label > Select a file to upload </label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="new"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my server code

```
var request = require('request');
var qs = require('querystring');
var multiparty = require('multiparty');
var util = require('util');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const xoauth2 = require('xoauth2');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    type: 'OAuth2',
    user: 'SenderMail@gmail.com',
    clientId: 'ClienId from google console developers website',
    clientSecret: 'clientSecret from google console developers website ',
    refreshToken: 'RefreshToken from Oauth2 Playground website',
    accessToken: 'accessToken from Oauth2 Playground website'
  },
});

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url === '/sendForm' && req.method === 'POST') {
    var body = "";
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
      body += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
      var mailOptions = {
        from: ' <sendermail@gmail.com>',
        to: 'Receivermail@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Sample mail',
        text: 'Hello !!!!!!!!!!!!!',
      };
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error');
        }
        else {
          console.log('Email Sent');
        }
      });
      res.end("successfully submitted");
    });
  }

  fs.readFile("./switchreal.html", (err, data) => {

    res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html', 'Content-Length': data.length });
    res.end(data);
  });

}).listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server Listening on 3000");
});
```

Comment: Ya here email is sending through node mailer only.You can check my code..Any help regarding this issue....

Comment: I know the process. I am able to upload the file but how can i attach it in the mail in server side code.

Answer (score 0):

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    type: 'OAuth2',
    user: 'SenderMail@gmail.com',
    clientId: 'ClienId from google console developers website',
    clientSecret: 'clientSecret from google console developers website ',
    refreshToken: 'RefreshToken from Oauth2 Playground website',
    accessToken: 'accessToken from Oauth2 Playground website'
  },
});
```

> > The below code solved my issue for sending the .pdf files

```
var mailOptions = {
        from: ' <sendermail@gmail.com>',
        to: 'Receivermail@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Sample mail',
        text: 'Hello !!!!!!!!!!!!!',
            attachments: [{
            // stream as an attachment
        filename: 'text4.txt',//your file name with proper extention
        content: fs.createReadStream('file.txt')                           
         }]
      };
```

[Nodemailer official documentation about adding attachments of file](https://community.nodemailer.com/using-attachments/)

hope this works for you

Mysimple code which send's the pdf file through mail using nodemailer 
https://github.com/Muthukumars1994/sow_app/blob/master/controller.js

Comment: I am able to attach a file in static way like reading a file from a system with particular extension but I want to attach any file like when you want to send a mail along with attach file you will click on attach file button and you will continue.In the same way I want to send a file in dynamic manner.

Comment: what  is your error message while sending mail using that dynmic files  console.log(error.message); `nodemailer error hander messsage`

Comment: When i use this code for attachment attachments: [
   
        {
            
            raw: 'Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=utf-8;\r\n' +
                 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=text.pdf;\r\n' +
                 '\r\n' +
                 'Hello world!'
        }
    ]  I am able to send pdf file with the name text.pdf  and downloaded it while opening it I am gettin failed to load.This means an empty pdf is cretaing not the file I am sending through the html form.

Comment: `attachments: [{
            filename: 'test.png',
             content:"your png content here"}]
  };`  I think the problem is with the Client to server {middle ware } you are using core node.js  am i write

Comment: Yes I am..I need that only what should I place in content field that is comming from a form when a file is selected to upload a file.

Comment: can i have your package.json file so that i can reproduce your code with my local

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152606/discussion-between-muthukumar-and-syed-ayesha-bebe).