# How to send PDF file as an attachment in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to send PDF file as attachment to user but when opening that file error is coming

"Failed to load PDF document."

I am using node mailer to send emails.

I am not getting the problem with it.

Please help!

Here is my code:-

```js
router.get('/file',function(req, res){
    var fromName = "Ikshit";
    var mailOptions={
        to: 'userEmailId@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Test',
        from: "email@gmail.com",
        headers: {
            "X-Laziness-level": 1000,
            "charset" : 'UTF-8'
        },
        attachments: [
   
        {
            
            raw: 'Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=utf-8;\r\n' +
                 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=text.pdf;\r\n' +
                 '\r\n' +
                 'Hello world!'
        }
    ],
        html: 'Text'
       
    }
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'email@gmail.com', 
            pass: 'password' 
        }
    });
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
        if(error){
           return res.send(err);
        }
        else{
            res.send({
                state:'success',
                message:"Send"
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and it definitely works

```
fs.readFile("E:/syed/nodejs/tasks/mail/mailwithdb/sheet.pdf",function(err,data){
var mailOptions={
from:' <mail@gmail.com>',
to:'mail@gmail.com',
subject:'Sample mail',
text:'Hello !!!!!!!!!!!!!',
attachments:[
{
    'filename':'sheet.pdf',
     'content': data,
     'contentType':'application/pdf'
}]
}
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(err,res){
if(err){
    console.log('Error');
}
else{
console.log('Email Sent');
}
})
});
```

Comment: No same issue fs.readFile is used when the file exists in the system 
But before sending email there is no sheet.pdf @ Syed Ayesha Bebe

Comment: You want to send file dynamic choosing of file???If want to send file through  the system it works good.Actually I too have this doubt:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635765/how-can-i-send-a-file-to-mail-in-html-form-using-http-request-in-nodejs-server-c

Comment: Yes I want to send dynamic file

Comment: oh! If I get any solution I will post

Comment: I am trying to send dynamic PDF file in attachment.
I am able to send that file in email but when opening that file after downloading it showing saying Failed to load pdf

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way...

```
var mailOptions = {
  from: 'foo@bar.com'.
  to: 'bar@foo.com',
  subject: 'an attached file',
  text: 'check out this attached pdf file',
  attachments: [{
    filename: '<fileName>',
    path: '<PDF file absolute path>'
    contentType: 'application/pdf'
  }]};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
     if(err){
       console.error(err);
       res.send(err);
     }
     else{
       console.log(info);
       res.send(info);
     }
  }
);
```

Comment: {
            filename: 'text.pdf',
            path: 'C:/Users/wta/Downloads/text.pdf',
            contentType: 'application/pdf'
}
By path the file where it will going to save ? @ hiren makwana

Comment: Got error 
code:"ESTREAM"
command:"API"
errno:-4058
path:"C:\Users\wta\Downloads\text.pdf"
syscall:"open"